# Ulfius: File upload creates broken files

Tags: c, file-upload

I am writing an application with the ability to upload a file via a HTML form using the ulfius 1.0.4 Framework in C.

If I upload a simple text file with a few lines of text everything works well.
But if I upload something more complex like a picture in the JPG format, the file created by the application is not like the original one the user has uploaded. The created picture cannot be displayed.
I opened the created file with a hex editor. The first 4 bytes were identical. But after that, I see parts that looks like an HTTP header.

This is my callback function:

```
int callback_upload_file(const struct _u_request * request, struct _u_response * response, void * user_data) {
int i;
const char **keys, *fileName, *fileContent;
size_t len;
keys = u_map_enum_keys(request->map_post_body);
for (i = 0; keys[i] != NULL; i++) {
    if (strcmp(keys[i], "dateiname") == 0) {
        fileName = u_map_get(request->map_post_body, keys[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(keys[i], "datei") == 0) {
        fileContent = u_map_get(request->map_post_body, keys[i]);
        len = u_map_get_length(request->map_post_body, keys[i]);
    }
}

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
fwrite(fileContent, sizeof (char), len - sizeof (char), fp);
fclose(fp);

response->string_body = msprintf("File uploaded!");
response->status = 200;

return U_OK;
}
```

This is my HTML form:

```html
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="upload" name="datei" type="file">
 <p>Dateiname <input id="filename" name="dateiname" type="text"></p>
 <input type="submit" name="hochladen" value="hochladen">
</form>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will be undefined behavior caused by an illegal memory access. Use a memory debugger if possible and you should fix it quickly. Also, are you aware the `sizeof(char)` is ALWAYS 1? And why are you subtracting `sizeof(char)` from the length anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.
It is possible to get the whole HTTP request. I am searching for the end of the header (\r\n\r\n) and writing the following data to the file.
This is the whole callback function:

```
int callback_upload_file(const struct _u_request * request, struct _u_response * response, void * user_data) {
int i;
const char **keys, *fileName, *fileContent;
size_t len;
keys = u_map_enum_keys(request->map_post_body);

for (i = 0; keys[i] != NULL; i++) {
    if (strcmp(keys[i], "dateiname") == 0) {
        fileName = u_map_get(request->map_post_body, keys[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(keys[i], "datei") == 0) {
        len = u_map_get_length(request->map_post_body, keys[i]);
    }
}

fileContent = strstr(request->binary_body, "\r\n\r\n");
fileContent += 4;

FILE *fp;
if ((fp = fopen(fileName, "wb")) == NULL) {
    return U_ERROR;
}

if ((fwrite(fileContent, 1, len - 1, fp)) != len - 1) {
    return U_ERROR;
}
fclose(fp);

response->string_body = msprintf("File uploaded!");
response->status = 200;

return U_OK;
}
```

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a binary file, you should use `"wb"` instead of just `"w"`. Because `"w"` could change the end of line character on some systems.

Also, there is no reason to subtract `sizeof(char)` from the length that I can think of, but I don't know what that framework is and whether it requires the operation or not.

One more thing, DO NOT IGNORE THE RETURN VALUE OF A FUNCTION, something could go really wrong but your code will continue anyway. All of the `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and `fclose()` return a value, the only one whose value can *probably* be ignored is `fclose()`, but the rest should not be ignored.